# Hibernate insert with id generation on insert trigger with sequence

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, sequence, batch-insert

Here my problem, I have a sequence in my oracle database and a trigger on insert to fetch the next value from the sequence and put it as id. With a tool like sql developer, it works perfectly.

My id is defined at this

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MY_SEQUENCE")
@SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "MY_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1, name = "MY_SEQUENCE")
private BigInteger jobId;
```

The problem is hibernate firstly read the next value of the sequence, set it as the id and then persist it. Then my database update my id with the next value of the sequence but that new id isn't "updated" in my code after my `.save(entity)`.

I read that I should use the `GenerationType.IDENTITY` but I would like to do batch inserts and I also read that with IDENTITY the batch inserts is not possible.

If possible, I would like to keep my trigger so like that hibernate doesn't have to call the database each time I insert and be able to do batch inserts.

Edit: I'll probably need to insert near a million of rows

Comment: Well, remove the trigger, and set the allocationSize to a bigger number than 1 (or don't set it at all)

Comment: Yeah but I would like to keep my trigger to reduce the number of calls to my database

Comment: That's why I advise you to not set allocationSize to 1. If you leave it to its default value (50), then hibernate needs only one call to get the next sequence value for every 50 inserts.

Comment: Yeah but even once in a while is too much as I'm going to insert near a million of rows (I've edited my original post for that info)

Comment: Excuting a query once in a while to increment a sequence is negligible comparing to inserting 1 million rows and writing them to the disk.

Comment: That's true. I'll check it out monday but would there be any other way to do it with the trigger?

Comment: Sure: you'd need to refresh then entity after each insert to ask what ID it generated for the entity, making it much much less efficient.

Comment: Ok and if I can come along to not refresh their ids, it would be possible?

Comment: "...but I would like to keep my trigger to reduce the number of calls to my database" - OK, then get rid of Hibernate.

Comment: Finally, I will remove the triggers. It's the easiest way to do it.